# Suggestion on Audiobook Converter

Tags: audio, ocr, converters

I'm gonna do a audiobook converter, and i want the audio to recognize the diagrams available on the book. The Ocr technique is not suitable i guess, is there suggestion on how to make it work?

I tried the ocr , but it's gonna take the text only .